# Position absolute, with a bottom of 0 only works for a parent with a height of 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Position absolute, with a bottom of 0 only works for a parent with a height of 100%. Once the height of the parent goes over 100%, setting it to bottom: 0 will no longer work. You won't be able to see that, in the code snippet itself - as it only allow the body height to be set up to 100%. How would I fix this?

```css
body {
  height: 200%;
}
#bottom {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='bottom'>
  bottom
</div>
```

Comment: you need to apply relative positioning to the container. abs in rel is one of the best css/design "tricks" that's under-documented...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not working because you are absolutely positioning it to the bottom of the viewport. If you want to absolutely position it to the bottom *relative* to the parent element, in this case, the `body` element, add `position: relative` to the element:

```css
html, body {
  height: 200%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
#bottom {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

Comment: How do I make sure that absolute position element don't flow over my other elements?

Comment: @frosty Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

The `position: absolute;` statement will position the object in relation to its first non static ancestor element. Source from: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

> absolute  The element is positioned relative to its first positioned
>   (not static) ancestor element

So you need to add either `position:relative;` or `position: absolute;` to the body tag as such:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 200%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div with id bottom to be at the bottom all times, you could use this

```
#bottom{
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

It will be something like an sticky footer...

Hope it helps T04435